# How can you dynamically resize Excel table dimensions? - Note: Not a named range or pivot table

Tags: microsoft-excel

How can the data range in Resize Table be dynamic as can be done for named ranges with =$B$2:INDEX($1:$1048576,COUNTA($B:$B),COUNTA($2:$2)). This formula is not accepted in "Resize Table".
[Snip it of :Resize Table"](https://i.stack.imgur.com/HQuII.png)

Comment: you can try using a named range in the resize table.  Use the formula for a named range then use `=INDIRECT("yourNamedRange")` to refer to it.  Not sure if it will work or not.

Comment: Why does it need to be more dynamic than a normal Table?